# having issues with usemin-cli and javascript with backticks

Tags: javascript

So I just got done working on a quick little drum kit project from Javascript30 and am working to have it optimized. I want to use nom package usemin-cli but it require that there are no backticks in the code. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Javascript

```js
function playSound(e) {
  const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  const key   = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  if (!audio) return;    //stops the function from running;
  audio.currentTime = 0; //rewind sound to start;
  audio.play();
  key.classList.add('playing');
};
function removeTransition(e) {
  if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return; //skips if the event is not a transform type
  this.classList.remove('playing');
};


const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
window.addEventListener('keydown', playSound);
```

Comment: It depends on how the HTML part of it is done

Comment: Hold on, i'll add the html